# ALM Octane Defect GET API

Tags: php, api, rest, alm

I am trying to pull the defects which are added in the ALM Octane through by ALM Octane API. I am able to pull the defects with query as below. But I am not getting the detailed information from the response (GET API).

I am using PHP Curl to pull all the defect information, but I am getting all the required information if i try to hit the url in the browser.

Could you please suggest on this?

```
public function getAlmDefects(){
        // echo "<h1>Hello</h1>";
        $query = urlencode('"component_udf EQ {name EQ \'CDP*\'}; phase EQ {name EQ \'Opened*\'}"');
        $almApi = "https://almoctane-ams.saas.microfocus.com/api/shared_spaces/123456/workspaces/12345/defects?fields=component_udf,phase&query=".$query;

        $username='username';
        $password='password';
        // $URL='<URL>';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$almApi);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
```

Output from the PHP:

```
{
total_count: 3,
data: [
    {
        type: "defect",
        id: "438191",
        phase: {
            type: "phase",
            id: "phase.defect.opened"
        },
        component_udf: {
            type: "list_node",
            id: "g74jy1pDFDDF55k17ryrm9"
        }
    }
]}
```

Output from the Browser URL:

```
{
total_count: 3,
    data: [
    {
        type: "defect",
        logical_name: "l674mlDFDFh5ove74dpr21",
        id: "438191",
        workspace_id: 7001,
        phase: {
            type: "phase",
            id: "phase.defect.opened",
            activity_level: 0,
            index: 500,
            workspace_id: 500,
            logical_name: "phase.defect.opened",
            name: "Opened"
        },
        component_udf: {
            type: "list_node",
            id: "g74jy1p1jkkp7s75DFD5k17ryrm9",
            logical_name: "g74jy1p1jkkp7s755k17ryrm9",
            index: 157,
            activity_level: 0,
            name: "DCP"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be an issue of URL encoding, perhaps? (The browser might do that differently, if you type in/copy&paste a URL that contains characters that need encoding.) `urlencode` encodes spaces as `+`, have you tried `rawurlencode` instead (`%20`)?

Comment: Thank you. But it is not working with rawurlencode. :(